# How to take data simultaneously from multiple Android device sensor and write to data stream?

Tags: arduino, sensors

I'm using an android device to retrieve data from the accelerometer and light sensors. I'm writing the data to an OutputStream which sends the data to an Arduino over Bluetooth. I want to create a string like the one below-
"X Value(Accelerometer), Y Value(Accelerometer),Light-Sensor value" 
But the problem is I can't get two value arrays from the same SensorEvent. It only seems to contain accelerometer values. This is what I have till now...

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
        int x = (int) event.values[0];
        int y = (int) event.values[1];

        String grav = x + "," + y;
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            if(actualTime - lastUpdate > 500) {
                mConnectedThread.write(grav.getBytes());
                lastUpdate = actualTime;
            }

        }
    }
    else if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
        actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        float value = event.values[0];
        if(mConnectedThread != null) {
            if(actualTime - lastUpdate > 500) {
                    String val = "" + value;
                    mConnectedThread.write("click".getBytes());
                    lastUpdate = actualTime;




            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the If you are just sending the x and y values from your Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY event.

In the Else you are sending the word "click" encoded as bytes when the Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT event occurs.  It does not seem likely that this is what you want

As you are triggering on 2 different events it's difficult to see how you could send all the data at once unless you store events, combine them later and then send.